# react unitTest className={{undefined}}

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

- in my react Project，i use jest+enzyme for my unitTest，when i
- `console(wrapper.debug())`
- the cmd show `className={{undefined}}`.
- why the className is undefined?
- how should i find my node from the className?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: `var TestComponent  = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div className={style.AskIconComponent} >
            <img src="assets/img/homepage_icon.png" />
        </div>;
    }
});`

Comment: i use style-loader css-loader ，what should i do ?

Comment: https://github.com/keyanzhang/jest-css-modules-example/